# Jest encountered an unexpected token because trying to import a file which Jest cannot parse

Tags: reactjs, testing, react-redux, jestjs, enzyme

PS E:\react\Code\UI> yarn test
yarn run v1.17.3
$ jest
 FAIL  src/App.test.js
  ● Test suite failed to run

```
Jest encountered an unexpected token

This usually means that you are trying to import a file which Jest cannot parse, e.g. it's not plain JavaScript.

By default, if Jest sees a Babel config, it will use that to transform your files, ignoring "node_modules".

Here's what you can do:
 • To have some of your "node_modules" files transformed, you can specify a custom "transformIgnorePatterns" in your config.
 • If you need a custom transformation specify a "transform" option in your config.
 • If you simply want to mock your non-JS modules (e.g. binary assets) you can stub them out with the "moduleNameMapper" config option.

You'll find more details and examples of these config options in the docs:
https://jestjs.io/docs/en/configuration.html

Details:

E:\react\Code\UI\src\mainpage.css:1
({"Object.<anonymous>":function(module,exports,require,__dirname,__filename,global,jest){body{font-size:12px;font-family:arial,sans-serif;background-size:200% 100%!important;height:100vh}
                                                                                             ^

SyntaxError: Unexpected token {

  1 | import React, { Component } from "react";
> 2 | import "../mainpage.css";
    | ^
  3 | import { connect } from "react-redux";
  4 | import propTypes from "prop-types";
  5 | import { fetchPost } from "../redux/action/postaction";

  at ScriptTransformer._transformAndBuildScript (E:\react../../../../Code/UI/node_modules/@jest/transform/build/ScriptTransformer.js:471:17)
  at ScriptTransformer.transform (E:\react../../../../Code/UI/node_modules/@jest/transform/build/ScriptTransformer.js:513:25)
  at Object.<anonymous> (E:\react../../../../Code/UI/src/page/Header.js:2:1)
```

Test Suites: 1 failed, 1 total
Tests:       0 total
Snapshots:   0 total
Time:        3.592s
Ran all test suites.
error Command failed with exit code 1.
info Visit https://yarnpkg.com/en/docs/cli/run for documentation about this command.

Answer (score 1):

## mock your css files

Jest has no idea what to do with css files. You need handle them in your jest config. There's really good info [here](https://jestjs.io/docs/en/webpack.html).

But essentially you need to add something like this to your jest config

```
// package.json (for CSS Modules)
{
  "jest": {
    "moduleNameMapper": {
      "\\.(jpg|jpeg|png|gif|eot|otf|webp|svg|ttf|woff|woff2|mp4|webm|wav|mp3|m4a|aac|oga)$": "<rootDir>/__mocks__/fileMock.js",
      "\\.(css|less)$": "identity-obj-proxy"
    }
  }
}
```